# Check if function is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration

Is this function integrable?

$f:[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$

[image]

I know that this function is bounded and it has points of discontinuity, I don't know how much and how to use boundedness of this function.

Comment: What tools do you know to check integrability?

Answer (score 2):

Since it is bounded and since the set of points at which it is discontinuous is countable and therefore it has Lebesgue measure $0$, it is Riemann-integrable.